# Sample app for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sample, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone point me to a solid sample app that shows how to use the new features and syntax of Rails 3?

It's been answered before for earlier versions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248371/whats-the-best-open-source-ruby-on-rails-project-to-learn-from), but I have not seen one for Rails 3.

Specifically the following:

- Routing
- Mailer
- new query syntax
- complex forms (how do these work with the new routing)
- unobtrusive js (specifically jQuery)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161002/ruby-on-rails-3-best-practices-example-open-source-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to check [Projexion](http://github.com/jpartogi/projexion). It uses Rails 3 beta 3.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice Rails 3 [overview](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-introrails3/index.html?ca=drs-) from IBM (surprisingly), along with links to additional resources.

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to [Ticketee](http://github.com/rails3book/ticketee). This is the application from [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [ror_ecommerce](http://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce). It's a starter app for an ecommerce site.
 Runs on Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great resource for sample apps: https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld.

It lets you choose front-end and back-end and mix/match because it uses the same API.

Hope this helps some people go beyond the basic to-do list app demos with more robust app demos.