# Ruby on Rails 3 best practices example open source application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please advice me some really great Ruby on Rails 3 application which i can use like example of best practices in Rails 3. The idea is i want to have the app on my hdd which i can use like reference when i have any questions how to implement some feature. It could be any blog engine, or app like Redmine does not matter but it should have almost all elements/functionality which is used to have any web application. And it should be done by using best practices from Ruby and Rails 3 point of view.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701622/sample-app-for-rails-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are definitely many apps on github to learn from. However a lot of solutions are very unique for particular contexts and everyone is always at some stage in their learning. Even in the best apps you should be able to find plenty to disagree with.

Here's a list of a few notable ones.

This is rubygems.org, strong community effort, has a lot of neat practices: https://github.com/rubygems/gemcutter

This project isn't necessarily best practices, but it's so loud and has so many people involved in working out all kinds of initially-written crap, that it may shape into something interesting: https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora

This is a popular e-commerce rails app for you to build upon. Haven't read the code, but again, it's pretty popular, which means, well supported by community: https://github.com/railsdog/spree

For more check out awesome github's explore page: https://github.com/explore.

P.S. Bucketwise is a Rails2 app created by Jamis Buck (of 37signals and Rails core). It's still worth watching even if you're looking for Rails 3 insights.

Comment: You can probably learn a lot from Bucketwise, but it is not Rails 3. Seems TS is looking for Rails 3 apps only.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. It's still worth it though.

Comment: I agree, hence the upvote ;-)

Comment: As of today (2011-02-03), the Diaspora code does not *look* good to me. By this I mean the code has a bunch of extra whitespace scattered, especially in the controllers. Some controller actions are way too long.

Answer (score 2):

I like the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guides. They're not really a complete app, but they are good examples of how things should be done and should be current.

You can also [search on Github](https://github.com/search?q=rails&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1) for Rails apps. The source code should be viewable, and if you have an account you can watch the various projects and see what's new.

Comment: yeah search on Github is good, but not all apps there written well even if it written on Ruby on Rails it still could be not in "Ruby or/and Rails way", so i am looking one or two apps which is approved by community as a well done in Rails and Ruby way.

Comment: Wading through Github is a good way to find code, but not an easy way to find *good* code. I think paxer was looking for some specific recommendations of well-written Rails applications.

Answer (score 1):

[rails3-devise-mongoid](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise) is a good one

as is [ror_ecommerce](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce)

Comment: also, consider running the [rails-best-practices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) gem against any code that you write

Comment: I think rails3-devise-mongoid is good for what it is intended -- to demonstrate how to use Rails 3, Devise, and Mongoid together, but I don't think it is a particularly good example of a full Rails 3 demonstration application. It is just too bare bones.

Answer (score 1):

Opinions of "best practices" vary widely. I would just read a ton of rails 3 code on github, and then read a ton more! By reading code, you will learn what is common in the rails world and develop your own best practices.

Comment: not exactly, i agree reading code is very useful, but there is a term - "Rails way", "Ruby way". Many things could be done on Ruby but not in "Ruby way" the same with Rails. I am trying to find best example.